# vb.net Collection of variables

Tags: vb.net, collections

How do I archive something like below ?
I want to be able to iterate through the `Collection` of `PartPrograms` in `Send()` but still can directly "access" the variables like I did in `Generate()` ->`(Program."VariableName".data).`

```
Public Class ProgramManager

    Private Program As New CavityProgram

    Sub Generate()  
        Program.MainProg.data = GetDataFunction() 'fill with data
        Program.MainProg.path = "C:\Foo.txt"
        [...]
    End Sub

    Sub Send()
        For Each prog In Program            'which collection do i need to do THIS
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(prog.path, prog.data)
        Next
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class CavityProgram
    Public MainProg As PartProgram
    Public Parameter As PartProgram
    Public Molding As PartProgram

    'Collection which stores all PartPrograms 

End Class

Public Structure PartProgram        'data object
    Public path As String
    Public data As String
End Structure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that fits my requirements

```
Public Class ProgramManager
    Public Programs As New List(Of PartProgram) 'Stores all partprograms

Sub Generate()            
    Programs.Add(New PartProgram With {
                    .name = "FU2PIECE.MPF",
                    .data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(pathTemplate & "\FU2PIECE.MPF", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8) _
                          .Replace("$DATE$", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss")) _
                          .Replace("$JOBINFO$", sji.ShortJobInfo) _
                          .Replace("$VERSION$", My.Application.Info.Version.Major & "." & My.Application.Info.Version.Minor)
                })

               [...]
End Sub

Sub Send()
      For Each prog In Me.Programs
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(root & "\" & prog.name, prog.data)
      Next
End Sub
```